# knockout validation secondary error messages not showing

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have my `jsfiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asad23/tRVCr/):

The problem is that the required field messages are showing when we hover over the "*" template, but when we entered invalid characters in the input box, the error message still remains one of required field rather Invalid characters or length of the fields.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it, after 20 minutes of stripping down the code. You owe me a beer.
Just move this init piece at the top of the code, before any observables are initialized.

```
// Knockout validation configuration.
ko.validation.init({
    insertMessages: true,
    messageTemplate: 'vmTemplate',
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tRVCr/3/

Comment: I am still having problem to get it working in my website project. Trying to figure out why is that. Also, in your jsFiddle there are few glitches: 1)pattern validation message isn't firing 2) once maxlength message is displays it remains there. Expected behavior is to get every validation message reset when model changes.